# Difference Max Value for primitive and primitve wrapper

Tags: java, size, primitive

I have java primitive int and its wrapper Integer ,do it mean that the int has the same Maximum value as Integer's maximum value ?

Comment: Yes, it does. (2147483647 [0x7fffffff])

Comment: I dont know why its alway 0% how do you increaes it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are the same for `int` and `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

All primitive wrappers, just wrap the primitives so they have the same range and the same  possible values.